# E-Mail functionality for moderators

Tags: 7, emails

I would like to allow moderator to send an e-mail to choosen user. The e-mail will be sent when the moderator observes a mistake made by the user. After that, moderator sends email with warning. How can I do it?

Comment: Look at [THIS](http://yadadrop.com/drupal-video/how-to-drupal-email-send-notifications-users), maybe can help you to resolve that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be, to give the moderators role the permission to use the users' individual contact forms ( in http://example.com/admin/people/permissions )

The messaging and notifications modules might have more functionality, however, they are still in alpha for drupal 7, so I would use them with great caution.